# How to extract substring matching the pattern using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, find

I would like to extract full name from the string using regular expression. How can i do that? This code gives me empty value of result. What's wrong?

```
var p = '№ 46/20 John Smith Newmore 23.01.2020';
var result = p.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/);
```

My expected result matches the regular expression:

**Existing data - string:**
'№ 46/20 John Smith Newmore 23.01.2020'

**Expected result:**
'John Smith Newmore'

Comment: Use `p.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]+/g,'').trim()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how can i use cyrillic symbols?

Comment: `p.replace(/[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z ]+/g,'').trim()` if you ask for Russian ones. Or `p.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+/g,'').trim()` to handle any Cyrillic chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i got the same "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[^Р°-СЏРђ-РЇС‘РЃa-zA-Z ]+/: Range out of order in character class"

Comment: That's a problem with your file encoding. But `p.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+/g,'').trim()` will work with all Cyrillic chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your answer, but i now i understand i need to compare inner text in div's i can't modify. How can i do my task without using replace?

Comment: Please update your question with your non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = '№ 46/20 John Smith Newmore 23.01.2020';

console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching anything between ***number followed by space*** and ***space followed by number*** using RegEx *lookbehind* and *lookahead*:

```js
var p = '№ 46/20 John Smith Newmore 23.01.2020';
var result = p.match(/(?<=\d+ ).+(?= \d+)/)[0];
console.log(result);
```